# FreeIPA without web UI or change of ports

Tags: httpd, freeipa

Can I install FreeIPA server without httpd (without web UI)??

Or at least can I change the ports?? (80->8880 and 443->8443)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot change the ports and configuration. Changing them will cause other parts of the system that expect JSON-RPC and XML-RPC end-points to fail because they assume the endpoints are available on 443, not anything else and there is no mechanism to negotiate an alternative port for the IPA framework and clients.

As result, client machines deployment will not work and IPA management from the command line will not work either. Web UI is just a JavaScript application that utilizes the same JSON-RPC endpoints which are used by command line tools.

Practically, the question is why you need to change the configuration? If you want to host other applications on FreeIPA master nodes, I do recommend to reconsider this. FreeIPA master nodes host your authentication infrastructure and co-hosting anything else is essentially expanding an attack surface for anyone interesting in hacking into the core of your infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I want to install replication server, but ports 80 and 443 are already occupied on this machine (with Apache as proxy server). 

In my infrastructure are two servers with CentOS 7 and all others with CentOS 6. FreeIPA server is installed on the first machine with CentOS 7. I want to install replication server on the second machine with CentOS 7. Installation on other servers is not possible, because FreeIPA master server and FreeIPA replica must be in the same version (package **ipa-server** is in version 4.1.0 on the CentOS 7 and in version 3.0.0 on the CentOS 6).

Comment: Just deploy one more virtual machine. It is really not recommended to put security-sensitive infrastructure together with application-level servers.

Comment: This answer doesn't quite cover the limitations well. For example, why would RPC be effected with a domain-based reverse-proxy where FreeIPA is listening on custom ports, but the reverse-proxy corrects (proxies) them to ports 80 and 443?

Answer (score 1):

While it is not recommended for production purpose, you could run freeIPA as a docker container with the ports 80 & 443 reassigned.

If you want to use the FreeIPA server not just from the host where it is running but from external machines as well, you can use the -p options to make the services accessible externally. You will then likely want to also specify the IPA_SERVER_IP environment variable via the -e option to define what IP address the server should put to DNS as its address. Starting the server would then be

```
docker run --name freeipa-server-container -ti \
    -e IPA_SERVER_IP=10.12.0.98 \
    -p 53:53/udp -p 53:53 \
    -p 8880:80 -p 8443:443 -p 389:389 -p 636:636 -p 88:88 -p 464:464 \
    -p 88:88/udp -p 464:464/udp -p 123:123/udp \
    -h ipa.example.test --read-only \
    -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    -v /var/lib/ipa-data:/data:Z \
    freeipa-server
```

See [the freeipa docker image info here](https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-container) for more information.

Answer (score -3):

It is a simple apache configuration, depending on what Linux distro you have, you can change that in httpd.conf.

In RHEL systems for example you will find the apache conf in:

```
  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Change inside the config: Listen 80 -> Listen 8880 (or anything you like).